# How to update data at the same time after an ajax post request

Tags: javascript

I am doing a ajax post request to

```js
fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(samepleData)
          })
          .then(response => {
            
            return response.json();
            
          })
```

and after the product has been added to the cart, I open a drawer to show all items in the cart using a GET request to the endpoint

```js
fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart.js')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then((cartData) => {
                        console.log(cartData);
                        if(cartData) {
                            
                                showCartDrawer(quick_shop_desktop_container, cartData);
                       
                        }
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
```

and everything is working, it is loading and fetching data, but now once I am in the cart drawer, I have an option to increase quantity and decrease quantity, so everytime someone clicks on increase quanity, it should again make a post request to the first endpoint, and the product will be updated, but the new info will not gonna be shown at the same moment, How to update all the data after the product quantity is increased without refreshing the page and at the same moment? I haven't woked with this type of conditions before, any guide please?

EXAMPLE CODE:-

```js
let samepleData = {
                    'items': [{
                     'id': myid,
                     'quantity': quantityValue
                     }]
                   };

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(samepleData)
          })
          .then(response => {
            
            return response.json();
            
          }).then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
              if (data) {
                fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart.js')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then((cartData) => {
                        console.log(cartData);
                        if(cartData) {
                            
                                showCartDrawer(quick_shop_desktop_container, cartData);
                       
                        }
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
              }
                ).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
              }
              else {
                addToCartBtn.innerHTML = `<span>Fail</span>`
              }
          })
})
```

And now inside the showCartDrawer

```js
test.innerHTML = cartData.items.map(cartItem => 
        `<div class="selliy-cart-item">
            <h2>${cartItem.price}</h2>
        </div>`
      ).join('');

increasequantityfromdrawer.addEventListener('click', () => {
   let newdata = {
                    'items': [{
                     'id': myid,
                     'quantity': newvalue
                     }]
                   };
   fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newdata )
          })
          .then(response => {

            return response.json();

          })
   
});
```

Comment: `it should again make a post request to the first endpoint, and the product will be updated`  - well, do that and show how you've done that - with what you've shown so far, nobody will be able to tell you how to do that, since you haven't shown enough of your site to help

Comment: @Bravo, I am not sure how to upload all my code here, but my question is about what are these type of practises called, when we click on a increase button, at the same movement I am doing a post request as shown, and then the product is added to the cart, but the new info will not gonna be updated at the same movement, either I have to refresh the page or reopen the cart drawer, I want to update all other info there only

Comment: it's called doing what you're doing right now - AJAX

Comment: @Bravo, do I need to again do the .map function to show all items once the quantity is increase and cart is updated with new values?

Comment: Each time new .map to all items in the cart?

Comment: i don't know - i can't see your data

Comment: @Bravo I updated the code for better understanding